# How to detect apple app is installed or not in web by javascript (only detect, not open the app)

Tags: javascript, ios

I need to detect where an app is installed in my web page. But Not open the app.
can this be implemented?how?

Comment: try this - https://github.com/ohh2ahh/AppAvailability , also this one - https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-appavailability

Comment: Well that depends on what you're using, can it be done from a normal website, I doubt it, but it can be done from a hybrid app using Cordova as @TusharWalzade has posted above

Comment: There is a web page I used before, it can indicate me to open or download the app which depends on the app is installed or not. That page works in ios 9 but doesn't in ios 8.

Comment: Hmmm i think there used to be a meta you can paste in the top of your page and would add a banner at the top of mobile safari “view this in app”. Maybe you could fire up some JS upon load to see if the banner is there and what does it say (install app or open app).